# Is it possible to extract the binary firmware of a feature phone?

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, binary

I am new at reverse engineering but very eager to learn. I have a feature phone it5081 and downloaded it's binary firmware. I have googled and came to know about tools like binwalk,firmware mod kit as well as their usage. But all the tutorials and discussions are on the binary firmwares of routers,smart tvs,android phones etc; none on feature phone firmwares. **I want to know if it is possible to extract the binary firmware of the feature phone somehow**.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you mean by "extract". AFAIK old phones typically had a monolithic firmware, without explicit partitions or filesystem. However, there still could be some kind of structure, especially for non-code parts like strings, layout of the menus, or images. There is no common standards for this so while there may be some commonality for the same series or manufacturer, it can also be different between any two phones, so the only sure way is to reverse the code and figure out how it works, though in some cases simple structures may be obvious from visual inspection (e.g. in a hex editor).